# How to limit result with JPQL @Query (without nativeQuery)?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a `JPQL` query for retrieving data from MySQL and although I can use `LIMIT 10` at the end of my MySQL query, I cannot us it in my `JPQL` clause:

Note: I simplified the query, I am not using this query for a simple SELECT:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT m.id AS id, m.title AS title FROM Movie m ORDER BY title LIMIT 10")
List<MovieProjection> listMovies();
```

Is it possible to get top 10 result **without using nativeQuery**?

Comment: I did not ask **PAGINATION** ! I just need one time select and limit result. So, why did not try to READ the question first before close it??? Open pls now!!!

Comment: @Moderator Why did you open the question?

Comment: It seems that pagination is a way to solve the problem by using a paginated query and asking for the first page.

Comment: @PierreDemeestere Thanks a lot, I will considerate it